# How can I get an HTML on a local IP using libcurl?

Tags: c++, sockets, libcurl, curlpp

At work, I have a device in another part of the building, which hosts a web page: `http://10.1.1.165/` which I need to parse.

I am attempting to use curlpp to retrieve the page and then libxml2 to parse the html.

Currently I have:

```
curlpp::Easy request;
request.setOpt(curlpp::options::Url(std::string("http://10.1.1.165/")));
std::list<std::string> headers;
headers.push_back(HEADER_ACCEPT);
headers.push_back(HEADER_USER_AGENT);
std::ostringstream responseStream;
curlpp::options::WriteStream streamWriter(&responseStream);
request.setOpt(streamWriter);
request.perform();
std::string re = responseStream.str();
htmlDoc = htmlReadDoc((xmlChar*)re.c_str(), NULL, NULL, HTML_PARSE_RECOVER | HTML_PARSE_NOERROR | HTML_PARSE_NOWARNING);
```

The code breaks on the line `request.peform();`
The output:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'curlpp::LibcurlRuntimeError'
  what():  No URL set!
```

I am very confused as I am following pretty identical instructions from the curlpp example code and an example provided here: *https://blog.laplante.io/2014/11/parsing-html-c-revisited/*

Am I forgetting to set some settings or incorrectly passing the url?

Comment: High bay area?  10.1.1.165 is an internal IP address.  Are you on the device's internal network with it?

Comment: @zzxyz Yes sorry by high bay I mean our factory area. We are on the same network.

Answer (score 3):

I have come to the conclusion that the C++ wrapper for libcurl is broken. Performing a curlpp::Easy request() does not work. I used the C version and everything works fine: [Read HTML source to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4370898/read-html-source-to-string/4371523#4371523)

Comment: I was going to suggest that, and then thought that was kind of a shitty non-answer to your question.  But...The C++ wrapper is entirely superfluous imo, except for FURTHER wrapping (Python/C#, etc)

Comment: Can you describe what is broken about it, to make this answer more complete?